# Android Studio 1.0 RC 1 Gradle build issues - Could not run build action using Gradle installation

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm getting error while importing gradle projects. The same when creating new project.

[image: Could not run build action using Gradle installation]
Using gradle from console builds project fine. 
So I think that the problem somewhere in the android studio.

I was changing the OS(win 7 to win 8.1), java version(1.6, 1.7, 1.8), android studio versions(from 0.8 to 1.0), gradle versions(1.10, 1.12, 2.1, 2.2), using gradel wrapper and downloaded gradle zips.

Nothing helped. 
I don't know how I can fix this, please help

**Added** [logs of android studio](http://pastebin.com/gaJZ3SvR)

Comment: [similar issue on AOSP issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=80354)

Comment: I've re-installed some of the environment and now it's working fine with jdk 8. The main change that I did - I've installed everything(JDK 8, android studio, Android sdk) to the default folders. Try this if you are facing the same issue

Comment: Can you post an answer and mark it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem - re-installed some of the environment and now it's working fine with jdk 8. The main change that I did - I've installed everything(JDK 8, android studio, Android sdk) to the default folders. Try this if you are facing the same issue